# Use package cleveref in Chapters

Tags: cleveref

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
  %------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
  %-----accent                      
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
  \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Preliminary}
 ....The crucial idea of the proof is to make use ..... (see \cref{fekete} in \cref{app}). 

\chapter*{Appendix}\label{app}
\begin{corollary}\label{fekete}

\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

I want to obtain

[image]

Comment: You never heard of `\appendix`?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Add `\appendix` before `\chapter*{Apendix}` and compile ...

Comment: Thanks. I add `\appendix    \chapter*{Appendix}\label{app}` However, I don't see any change.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load the `latexsym` package. It was superseded more than 20 years ago by the much more comprehensive `amssymb` package.

Comment: @Mico Yes I compile however, the problem still persist.

Comment: @Schüler -- The problem "persists" because your document setup has a fundamental flaw. If there's a single unnumbered appendix chapter, it's overkill to adduce the `cleveref` machinery to create a cross-referencing call-out. You could (actually, *should*) write "... according to corollary X in the appendix". In my view, though, it does make sense to number the appendix chapters, even if there's just one chapter of this type. What you would have to do -- in addition to inserting that loathsome `\appendix` instruction -- is change `\chapter*{Appendix}` to `\chapter{Supplemental Material}`.

Comment: Thank you. So I think I write simply "... according to corollary X in the appendix".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `\appendix` before your line `\chapter*{Appendix}` and delete the `*` to get a numbered appendix. Then `cleveref` can work.

Please see the code (I changed your label to better ones!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preliminary}
The crucial idea of the proof is to make use ..... (see \cref{cor:fekete} in \cref{cha:app}). 

\appendix
\chapter{Supplemental material}\label{cha:app} % <=======================================
\begin{corollary}\label{cor:fekete}

\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

and page 3:

[image: page 3]

with better chapter heading and no double Apendix :-)

Comment: Thank you but after compilation, I find Appendix A
Appendix
Corollary A.0.1. I hope to find only Appendix without A.

Comment: Please after compilation, see page 3. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Schüler - If you want to have a numbered appendix, you must switch from `\chapter*{...}` to `\chapter{...}`. If you do *not* want to number the appendix, there's simply no point in using the `\cref` machinery to create a cross-referencing call-out; instead, just write "in the appendix".

Comment: Thank you but, is there another idea instead `\appendix`?

Comment: @Schüler `\appendix` is born for that purpose, i.e. this is the standard solution.

Comment: I mean, the problem exists in page 3 because I find '' Appendix A Appendix''.